# How to create and populate Parquet files in HDFS using Java?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, parquet

What is the best way to create and populate Parquet files in HDFS using Java without the support of Hive or Impala libraries?

My goal is to write a simple csv record (String) to a Parquet file located in HDFS.

All the questions/answers previously asked are confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like [parquet-mr](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr) is the way to go. They provide implementations for Thrift and Avro. Own implementations should be based on [ParquetOutputFormat](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/hadoop/ParquetOutputFormat.java) and might look similar to [AvroParquetOutputFormat](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-avro/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/avro/AvroParquetOutputFormat.java) and [AvroWriteSupport](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-avro/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/avro/AvroWriteSupport.java) which does the actual conversion.